# Chrome extension to recognize new protocol (instead of http)

Tags: url, plugins, google-chrome-extension, protocols

Is this possible? If a link was to "newprotocal://randomwords", I need chrome to recognize that and run some code in a background page. Right now, it just makes a google search for it. If not, possible to do this with a plug-in?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this with Chrome Extensions. Chrome restricts a lot. I believe you can do this through the OS though.

Answer (score 2):

Can your design change to support the the [Omnibox API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/omnibox.html)?

If not, perhaps you can try and make use of the new HTML5 feature [window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler) which allows web sites to register themselves as possible handlers for particular protocols.

It has been implemented in Chrome 13 since [issue:11359](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=11359) has been fixed.

Comment: Note that explicit extension support for `registerProtocolHandler` is still pending (follow [Chrome bug 86115](http://crbug.com/86115) to track its progress).